# Stop Hibernate from creating not-null constraints

Tags: java, hibernate, constraints, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

Is there a way to stop Hibernate from creating not-null constraints for properties annotated with `@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` when using `hbm2ddl = create`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation of Hibernate Validator:

> #### [6.1. Database schema-level validation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-checkconstraints.html#validator-checkconstraints-db)
>
> Out of the box, Hibernate Annotations
>   (as of Hibernate 3.5.x) will translate
>   the constraints you have defined for
>   your entities into mapping metadata.
>   For example, if a property of your
>   entity is annotated `@NotNull`, its
>   columns will be declared as `not null`
>   in the DDL schema generated by
>   Hibernate.
>
> If, for some reason, the feature needs
>   to be disabled, set
>   `hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl` to
>   `false`. See also [Table 2.2, “Built-in
>   constraints”](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#table-builtin-constraints).
>
> You can also limit the DDL constraint
>   generation to a subset of the defined
>   constraints by setting the property
>   `org.hibernate.validator.group.ddl`.
>   The property specifies the comma
>   seperated, fully specified classnames
>   of the groups a constraint has to be
>   part of in order to be considered for
>   DDL schema generation.

For more details about the `org.hibernate.validator.group.ddl` property, see also the section [4.1.2. Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/additionalmodules.html#d0e3900).